# Integral formula

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, divergence-operator

Could someone please help me understand why this formula is correct

$$\int_{V'}\nabla\times[\;G\underline{A}\;]dv' = \oint_{S'}G\underline{A}\times d\underline{s}$$

I don't understand the mathematical concept that I should use here.

Comment: Could you detail what $GA$, $V'$ and $S'$ are?

Comment: Your formula looks off by a -ve sign (unless $\underline{s}$ is an inner pointing normal for the volume $V'$).

Comment: G is scalar function
A is a vector function
and V' is volume
and S' is surface the enclosed that volume